# "Failed to parse source for import analysis" error occurred

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I m VUE Beginner. So I want to create simple vue single file component. I added following code snippets and run my server using `yarn vite` Then I got following error. Could anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

[image]

App.vue

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default{

  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
       
    </div>
    <style>
        .red{
            color:red;
        }

        .blue{
            color:blue;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="module" src="index.js">  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "signup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "vite": "^2.7.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.26"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you use **yarn vite** and also when did you use that command? As the [documentation says](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project) you must use ```yarn create vite``` command for creating a vite project.